# java: extract points from a txt file

Tags: java, extractor

Suppose I have a txt file called "filename". The data inside is as following,

```
N
12  39
34  23
12  22
5   7
7   10
11  8
  .
  .
  .
```

left column contains the x value of each point. Right column contains y value of each point. N is the number of lines Point data that follow. I need to extract all the Point data and store it in a data structure(such as List). Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What are you stuck on? Reading the file? Picking a data structure? Creating/inserting into the data structure?

Comment: Using the Scanner class on a File class will get you quite a lot of the way there

Comment: I try to using Arraylist to store those points, but I just don't know how to separate these two columns and assign it to x or y values of a point..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File file = new File(filepath);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file.getInputStream);
int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) // reads n-1 points, if you have n points to read, use n instead of "n-1"
{
    line = br.readLine();
    StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");

    int x = Integer.parseInt(t.nextToken());
    int y = Integer.parseInt(t.nextToken());

    // do whatever with the points
}
```

This would work for something like this as an input file,

```
3           // line 1 
1 2         // line 2
3 4         // line 3
```

Comment: From looking at this (I have learned something new, thank you) it looks like t.nextToken(); returns a string anyway so the cast is not necessary

Comment: Note that this would break with the given input, since it doesn't account for N.

Comment: Thanks , made the edits.

Comment: @AnkitRustagi Will you count one more line? Since N itself is a line and I don't want to parse that line.

Comment: @catchwisdom I hope it should be clear by now how to do that

Comment: yeah anyways made the edit as well.

Comment: If we are going that way then are you sure about int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());, because the "N" is a string not an int

Comment: yes but from the question, N seems to be a number stating the number of pairs of points to read.

Answer (score 1):

My solution using `Scanner` instead of `BufferedReader`/`StringTokenizer`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("filename"));
int n = scanner.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int x = scanner.nextInt();
    int y = scanner.nextInt();

    // do something with the point or store it
}
```

It's probably not as fast, but it's much easier to read and write.